# Deploying Sass/Haml/Coffeescript on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I've read the asset pipeline articles on heroku.com, and it looks like I'm doing almost everything right, but I'm getting 404s on my application.js and application.css.

Comparing the fingerprints, I can see that the url helper is giving me a different answer than what is in the request. Here's what I can see on Heroku:

```
$ heroku run bash
Running `bash` attached to terminal... up, run.1960
~ $ ls public/assets
application-50ce5a3afe618615672a7e1ee461035b.css     bootstrap.css-8bad3d2500139cbdf1d0c7c9c035fc1f.map.gz
application-50ce5a3afe618615672a7e1ee461035b.css.gz  bootstrap-theme.css-f1ed2b42047809f68d201f3559550d16.map
application-5e5228fa658dcbd73b15ab478802b54e.css     bootstrap-theme.css-f1ed2b42047809f68d201f3559550d16.map.gz
application-5e5228fa658dcbd73b15ab478802b54e.css.gz  fontawesome-webfont-57144723bcb14fce1497e62ea6b81fbe.eot
application-7d1d546aa11d09b7a74cda86f09b273f.css     fontawesome-webfont-583792bbfa3fd24f9ba26bd5d5741afe.ttf
application-7d1d546aa11d09b7a74cda86f09b273f.css.gz  fontawesome-webfont-ad8c4e159be2c0459c78484f3a0a451e.woff
application-9f14cf75fbb8c9bba0cb61791d45ccbc.js      fontawesome-webfont-ca4357fcad960eba2cdbcc610be8353f.svg
application-9f14cf75fbb8c9bba0cb61791d45ccbc.js.gz   glyphicons-halflings-regular-171c97066e4db52896df4e14c2905e8e.eot
application-a709048a59192f689302f9983808bc06.js      glyphicons-halflings-regular-7206a6a5553d1b106dc988b6af7e29df.ttf
application-a709048a59192f689302f9983808bc06.js.gz   glyphicons-halflings-regular-a6d95d67a6db3f50ff64b2103e8c9348.woff
application-ec90d79697332b5eff4e6bc89e0f868b.js      glyphicons-halflings-regular-e327cd5918c69ba34cb1c92b9c7c424a.svg
application-ec90d79697332b5eff4e6bc89e0f868b.js.gz   manifest-cac4929f095c2cf99a97058140de8a3a.json
bootstrap.css-8bad3d2500139cbdf1d0c7c9c035fc1f.map   twitter

$ heroku run rails console
Running `rails console` attached to terminal... up, run.7999

Loading production environment (Rails 4.0.0)
irb(main):001:0>
irb(main):002:0* puts helper.asset_path("application.js")
/assets/application-9f14cf75fbb8c9bba0cb61791d45ccbc.js
```

And in Chrome, I see the request is for:

```
http://myapp.herokuapp.com/assets/application-9f14cf75fbb8c9bba0cb61791d45ccbc.js
```

So it looks like what I am requesting is there, is what the helper is specifying, and I'm still getting a 404. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your application set up to use [`static assets`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production)?

Comment: Yes, this was the piece of the puzzle I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try running `rake assets:precompile` before adding to your repo and pushing to Heroku.